# Calling c methods from C#

Tags: c#, .net, c, windows-forms-designer

I have to call my c method from c# coding.I have included .c file in our project.In c file i have test() method.I don't know how to call in c#. I don't want to convert my c project to dll file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to convert my c project to dll file.

You might not want to do that, but it's the only way. The most common solutions to your problem are:

- Compile C code into unmanaged DLL and call it using p/invoke.
- Compile C code into a COM server and use COM interop.
- Wrap the C code in a C++/CLI mixed mode assembly which you can add to the C# project as a reference.